# How can I get undefined unevaluated integrals to be treated like number?

Tags: symbolic

I am working with commutators like this $$ \left(a \int f \, \mathrm dt\right) * a - a * \left(a \int f \, \mathrm dt\right),$$

```
comm[A_, B_] := ExpandAll[A ** B - B ** A //. a ** ad :> ad ** a + 1]
comm[-a Integrate[f[1, t], t], a ** a]
```

where $a$ is a ladder operator, and I would like the integral to be treated like a number and factored out. For some reason, this expression isn't simplifying to zero.

I tried

```
Integrate /: NumberQ[Integrate[expr_]] = True;
```

which doesn't seem to help, and also

```
Integrate /: NumberQ[Integrate[expr__]] = True;
```

and

```
Integrate /: NumberQ[Integrate[__]] = True;
```

seem to be working but both give the error

> Integrate called with 1 argument; 2 or more arguments are expected.

What is the correct syntax for this command?

Note that I also use a variety of rules such as

```
A_ ** (B_ + C_) := A ** B + A ** C
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Can you please include Mathematica code of your commutator in the question?

Comment: I meant the exact expression with `Integrate` and `f` and `a` ...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, the exact expression is at the top of my post and it isn't simplifying. I've figured out a related problem is that `Sy**a**a-a**a**Sy` evaluates to zero but `Sy^2**a**a-a**a**Sy^2` does not, for some reason Sy^2 is being treated differenty. I've already used `Sy /: NumberQ[Sy] = True;` to set Sy to be commutative but maybe this doesn't work for Sy^2

Comment: Yes, but the expression at the top is in $\LaTeX$ form. Please include Mathematica version of this expression (e.g. `a * Integrate[f, t] ** ...`).

Comment: For example `comm[-a Integrate[f[1,t],t], a**a]` will be kept and outputted as $a ** a ** (a \int f(1, t) dt) - (a \int f(1, t)  dt) ** a ** a$

Comment: Try this: `(a*Integrate[f[t], t])*a - a*(a*Integrate[f[t], t])` returning 0.

Comment: I don't think * would work because * is commutative multiply whereas ** is used for non commutative multiply which is what i need to use for ladder operator commutators

Answer (score 1):

Suppress evaluation at all instances

```
  SetAttributes[comm, HoldAll];
  comm[A_, B_] := A ** B - B ** A -> 
    ReleaseHold[ExpandAll[Hold[A ** B - B ** A] /. {HoldPattern[a ** ad_] :> ad ** a + 1}]]


    comm[-a Integrate[f[1, t], t], a ** a]
```

$$(-a \int f(1,t) \, dt)\text{**}a\text{**}a-a\text{**}a\text{**}(-a \int f(1,t) \, dt)\to (-a \int f(1,t) \, dt)\text{**}(a\text{**}a+1)-(a\text{**}a+1)\text{**}(-a \int f(1,t) \, dt)$$